# Delete a user and all files owned by this user

Tags: command-line, users

I have used `deluser` without the parameter `--remove-all-files`:

```
$ deluser 'user'
```

Is there a way other than `rm -r /home/user` to remove all files owned by a user now (since I have already executed deluser)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will have to manually find files, which probably was what `deluser` would do.

Please note `--remove-all-files` is *not* the same as `rm -r /home/user`. The latter only removes the homedir (which may include files not owned by that user, although not usual), the former removes *all* files owned by that user from the system. At least if [the manpage is to be trusted](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?8+deluser).

GNU `find` has a `-user` test, so you can do `find / -user xxx` to find all files owned by user `xxx`. `xxx` would be the user name, and can (and in this case *will* have to, as the user no longer exists) be the user's numeric ID. `find` also has a `-delete` option, so

```
find / -user xxx -delete
```

Should do it, although I've not tested the command with all the options at the same time.

**EDIT: Numeric ID:** The reason why I said you have to use a numeric ID is because, as you already deleted the user, his entry in `/etc/passwd` was deleted (it had, along with other stuff, the user ID, along with his username).

So, if you didn't remove his homedir, one of the easiest ways is to just query for the ID of the owner of that homedir:

```
stat -c %u /home/user/
```

(`stat` is a tool to read filesystem data. `-c %u` tells `stat` how to write its output, here I'm asking it to simply output the user ID)

If you like one-liners, you can even chain both commands:

```
find / -user $(stat -c %u /home/user/) -delete
```

(Of course you may prefer to run it first with no `-delete` to make sure there's nothing you want to keep, and to catch any mistake you've made writing the rest of the command. Mistakes when doing recursive deletion operations on `/` are not for the faint of heart.)

Comment: You can also use the `-exec` option of find to run a custom rm command if you want a bit more control over your deletions, but I've never tried that so YMMV.

Comment: True, either that or passing the output to `rm` using `xargs` (but this will probably hit the argument limits if there are too many results), but look at `-depth`, quoting the info manual: "If your \`find' command removes directories, you may find that you get a spurious error message when \`find' tries to recurse into a directory that has now been removed.  Using the \`-depth' option will normally resolve this problem." (and later on the same section, "(\`-delete' implies `-depth' anyway)")

Comment: @njsg Well I get:
`find: 'user' is not the name of a known use`

Comment: @pl1nk: as I said, you will have to use the user's numeric ID — as you already deleted the user, there is no mapping in `/etc/passwd` that lists the user and his ID. You will have to find the numeric id. Do `stat -c %u /home/user/`, it should give you the numeric user id, use that as `xxx` above.

Comment: @njsg You are right I haven't read the last part of your question.

Comment: @pl1nk glad it helped! I updated the answer to add a part on finding the numeric ID.

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to re-add the user with `adduser`, specifying the old UID, and then run `deluser` again, this time with the `--remove-all-files` flag.

Suppose, for instance, that the user had username **`alice`** and UID **`1001`**:

```
sudo adduser --uid 1001 alice
sudo deluser --remove-all-files alice
```

Answer (score 3):

gnu find has the options -nouser and -nogroup, look it up in `man find`. With these options you can find all files in your filesystem(s) that have no corresponding user in /etc/passwd. If you have not created a new user with the old uids of your deleted users, this is a possibility to find these orphaned files.

However, you might find more files - not only those who belonged to your deleted one.

Comment: I believe you have the best answer!...  
"$ find / \\( -nouser -o -nogroup \\) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf"
The command finds all files which don't have a user nor group and removes them automatically.